# Using gps coordinates in rotation component of Aframe

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, aframe

I have written javascript to fetch gps coordinates. I want to use those coordinates in rotation component of Aframe, like

`<a-entity rotation="Longitude Latitude 0"> </a-entity>`

Please help. If it is not possible, will I have to write a new component to do such a thing?

Comment: Create a new component that sets the rotation based on the data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I pass gps coordinates to A-frame component property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63319887/how-do-i-pass-gps-coordinates-to-a-frame-component-property)

Comment: but there is no answer in it.

Comment: They look like the same question. I would consolidate in one