# How do I pass gps coordinates to A-frame component property?

Tags: javascript, aframe

I am trying to pass value of latitude to the a-frame component as defined below. I am unable to do so. Please help. It seems trivial, I am new to Javascript.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Component Add</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Hello, WebVR! • A-Frame">
    <script src="js/aframe.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/three.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<script>
 
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

function showPosition(position){
 
 var Latitude = position.coords.latitude;
 var Longitude = position.coords.longitude;
 var arr = [Latitude, Longitude];
 return arr;
}
// Store returned value in a variable
 
var all = showPosition(position);
// Displaying individual values

console.log(all[0]); 

AFRAME.registerComponent('log', {
  schema: {
    message: {type: 'number', default: all[0]},
  },

  init: function () {
    console.log(this.data.message);
  }
});        
</script>

<a-scene inspector="" keyboard-shortcuts="" screenshot="" vr-mode-ui="" device-orientation-permission-ui=""  log="">
       
  <!-- <a-sky src="MonValley_A_LookoutPoint_8k.jpg"></a-sky>-->
 <a-assets>
    <img id="sky" src="img/mon.jpg">
  </a-assets>
  <a-sky src="#sky" material="" geometry="" ></a-sky>    

 <div class="a-loader-title" style="display: none;">Hello, WebVR! • A-Frame</div>

</a-scene>

 </body>
</html>
```

In the debugger it shows a message **TypeError:position is undefined**

Comment: Help people to help you. Share runnable code for helpers to debug and easily suggest solutions. https://glitch.com/~aframe is great!

Comment: I have added the full code

Comment: Make your code easy to run. Glitch is great https://glitch.com/~aframe people will be able to debug and suggest alternatives on a single click

Comment: FWIW, you’re calling showPosition and passing a position variable that it’s not defined. The error makes sense

Comment: what should I be doing?

Comment: Share a full runnable version of your code in Glitch https://glitch.com/~aframe